# Accessing cpu registers in python

Tags: python, cpu-registers

Is there any way to access cpu registers in Python (under Linux)?

Lets say you would like to print the value of rip or rsp in your python program. How can you achieve this?

Comment: What's the point of this? The registers reflect the state of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like you want C, not Python.

Comment: Not Python, but you may want to check out the unix.stackexchange - see [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111588/monitor-cpu-registers) for example

Comment: In CPython `rip` will always point to something like `PyEval_EvalFrameEx` and `rsp` will depend on interpreter internals too... So you question sounds absurd.

Comment: Python is a high-level language designed to run on multiple platforms and CPU's.  Accessing cpu registers cannot be portable.  For example, ARM registers are different from x86 registers.